# how to actor render to Particular posistion without any inputprocess

Tags: libgdx

i'm new to libgdx, I'm trying to make a sprite move to particular target. I can make the sprite move perfectly in x position. i`d move to target position without inputprocess like a enemy. I've tried a few different things but at this point its just guessing and checking.

o(actor) render to target from any position of screen.

/*

```
                  o((qx,qy)actor)
                   |
                   |
                   v
```

((lx,ly)actor)o--->target(tx,ty)<------o((rx,ry)actor)

*/
pls helpme ...

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly but but you could subtract the source point and the destination point and graduelly translate the sprite.
Remember: In libgdx y=0,x=0 is bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/). It's perhabs some overkill to just linealy progress a value across time but it will handle all the things you need. Just read the [GetStarted page](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wiki/GetStarted) on the GoogleCode project of it to learn the basics.

Also, you can run a demoApp that showcase it's potential.

- [Here it's in HTML5](http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/gwt/demo.html)
- [Here it's in Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/downloads/detail?name=tween-engine-demo-6.3.0.zip)
- [And here it's in Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aurelienribon.tweenengine.demo)

All three are done in LibGDX by the way.